# javax package contains different packages in two different projects

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, ejb

Two projects are open in NetBeans at the same time.

One of the projects is from javaeetutorial5 example zip, it's called bookstore2.
It needs javax.persistence.entity to compile as it uses @Entity annotation.
This one does not build due to javax.persistence not found.
If I typed 'javax.' then persistance would not be in the list.

Another project is a brand new ejb application with a bean and a web.
If I typed 'javax.' then persistence would autocomplete and entity would autocomplete too. The project builds just fine.

Could the reason be that the brand new project was created by NetBeans under its projects folder ~/NetBeansProjects, while the example projects were all unzipped into a subfolder under ~/NetBeansProjects/javaeetutorial5/examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,the solution to Bookstore/Bookstore2 not building is the last post by Dinath [Here](http://forums.netbeans.org/post-151062.html).
Go to Project properties/Libraries, add library, scroll down to Persistency and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Include javaee-api-6.0.jar (file name may vary - J2EE jar) in the project classpath

Comment: There are both javaee-api-7.0.jar and javaee-api-6.0.jar under netbeans731/enterprise/modules/ext. Do I need to add 6.0 to Project properties/Libraries/Compile time libraries?

Comment: if jdk7 use javaee-api-7.0.jar else if jdk6 use javaee-api-6.0.jar

Comment: Bookstore2 already has JDK 1.7 (Default) under its libraries tree (same as my own project where javax.persistency is visible). I tried adding avaee-api-7.0.jar into Properties/Libraries/Compile time libraries list to no avail.

Comment: Bookstore is referenced by Bookstore2. Bookstore is missing library toplink. Is this related to this discussion: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72143 ?

Answer (score -1):

The project `Bookstore2` build path was not configured correctly in `netbeans`, each project in `netbeans` has its own build path configured. If one project has `javax` package it doesn't mean all the project in `netbeans` has it.

For more information on how to configure project in netbeans [see](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-configuring)

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting what's the difference. Both projects have jdk 1.7 and glassfish 4.0 listed under the libraries node. What am I missing?